# How succesful ssl_bump should look like in wireshark?

Tags: ssl, proxy, squid

I have set up a squid proxy between two servers in which I use ssl_bump. The config is ([source](https://serverfault.com/questions/841657/using-squid-to-upgrade-tls-connections-to-tls-1-2)):

```
http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=8MB cert=/usr/local/etc/squid/certs/domain.com.cert key=/usr/local/etc/squid/certs/domain.com.private

always_direct allow all  
ssl_bump server-first all
sslproxy_cert_error allow all  
sslproxy_flags DONT_VERIFY_PEER  
sslcrtd_program /usr/local/libexec/squid/ssl_crtd -s /var/ssl_db -M  4MB 
sslcrtd_children 8 startup=1 idle=1
```

I tcpdump-ed the client and analyzed it with wireshark on proxy machine. Let's say A be the source, B the destination and C the proxy.

1. Why in wireshark only A & B are listed as sources and destinations? Is it the desired behavior? How could I make B think its communicating with A?
2. If A uses TLSv1.0 and B expects TLSv1.2, assuming the bumping on proxy is successful, which version would be shown in wireshark?

Comment: Your question is not very clear and confusing with A, B, and C since you also do not show the commands attempted. But maybe only A and B are shown as sources and destinations because the commands attempted are not using the C proxy at all? And as for the second point, you should get TLS 1.0 between A and C and TLS 1.2 between C and B

Comment: @PatrickMevzek They must go through the proxy since they are visible in tcpdump done on that proxy machine (i.e. C), otherwise how would these be there if it is a physically separate machine? Still, there is *no* A-C and C-B connections listed there, only A-Bs. ||
What do you mean by commands? There's a custom app on A running on jboss with proxy parameters to C, squid on C is using only config attached, and B is an external endpoint. Tcpdump read by wireshark is made as `tcpdump -i any -A -vv -s 0 -x -w dump.out`